# Can a makefile enforce dependency restrictions in C++

Tags: c++, makefile

We are refactoring our code base, and trying to limit the direct dependencies between different components.  Our source tree has several top level directories: src/a, src/b and src/c.

We want to enforce a set of restirctions:

- Files in a cannot depend of files in b or c
- Files in b can depend on files a but not c
- Files in c can directly depend on files in b but not a

Enforcing the first one is simple.  I have an implicit rule like this:

```
build/a/%.o : src/a/%.cpp
  $(CXX) -I src/a $(OTHER_FLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

If a file under a tries to include a header file from b or c, the build fails as the header is not found.

The second rule has a similar rule, which specifies src/a and src/b as include directories.  The problem arises with building c.  The following is allowed.

```
src/c/C.cpp
#include "b.h"
void C() { ... }

src/b/b.h
#include "a.h"
class B { ... };

src/a/a.h
class A { ... };
```

Here, a file from c includes a file from b (allowed), which in turn includes a file from a (also allowed).  We want to prevent code like this:

```
src/c/C_bad.cpp
// Direct inclusion of a
#include "a.h"

src/c/c_bad.h
// Direct inclusion of a
#include "a.h"
```

For the allowed case to compile, the compile command for building files in src/c must include a -Isrc/a, but that allows the second cases to also compile.

I suspect that the answer to my problem is writing a script which looks at the dependencies generated from the compiler, finds potentially illegal dependencies and then looks at the source files to determine if this is a direct dependency.  Is there a reasonable way to do this combining the compiler and/or makefile constructs?

If it matters, we are using GNU Make 3.81 and g++ 4.5.3, but would like to be portable if possible.

**Update**

We are looking for something where it takes effort to violate the rules, not one where it takes effort to follow the rules.  (Past experience has shown that the latter is unlikely to work.)  While there are some good ideas in the other answer, I'm accepting the one that says to write a script, since that is the one that takes the most effort to work around.

Thanks to everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the fact that you're applying this on an existing code base, I would opt for the "validation script" approach.

So instead of modifying the build process and severing dependencies one at a time as the build fails, you get presented with a list of files that are non-complaint. You can then refactor your codebase having the "big picture" in mind and any changes you make will be built using the same Makefiles as before thus simplifying testing and debugging.

Once refactored, the analysis script can continue to be used as a compliance checker to validate future updates.

A possible starting point for such an analysis would be to use [`makedepend`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend) or `cpp -MM`. For example, using the cpp/h files you've listed in the question:

```
[me@home]$ find .
.
./b
./b/b.h
./a
./a/a.h
./c
./c/C_bad.cpp
./c/C.cpp
./c/c_bad.h

[me@home]$ cpp -MM -Ia -Ib -Ic */*.cpp 
C_bad.o: c/C_bad.cpp a/a.h
C.o: c/C.cpp b/b.h a/a.h

[me@home]$ # This also works for header files
[me@home]$ cpp -Ia -Ib -Ic -MM c/c_bad.h 
c_bad.o: c/c_bad.h a/a.h
```

It should be reasonably straight-forward to parse those output to determine the dependencies of each cpp file and flag up those that are non-compliant.

The drawback to this approach is that it cannot differentiate between direct and indirect dependencies, so if that matters you may need to include an extra step to inspect the source and pick out direct dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But it takes some manual effort and discipline.

When building C you can depend on headers in src/b/*.h.

Inside project B any header files in the main directory should be self-contained and not have dependencies on other projects. You also need a subdirectory inside B src/b/detail/*.h. In here header files are allowed to include src/a/*.h and src/b/*.h but this is a private implementation detail and only available to source files for the b project.

Comment: If I do #include "a.h" from src/b/b.h (not from the detail directory), can the build be made to fail, or would we have to rely on a code review to catch that?  It seems that you could also include c/c.h from src/b/detail/b.h and not have the build fail.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `-I` options target-specific:

```
build/b/%.o: CPPFLAGS += -Isrc/a
build/c/%.o: CPPFLAGS += -Isrc/b
```

This is specific to gnu-make, though, so it's not portable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change your include path to `-Isrc` for everything. Include statements then have the complete relative path

```
#include <a/a.h>
```

for example. This makes it much easier to check the code automatically (perhaps in a commit hook rather than the makefile).

---

Alternatively, you *could* do something nasty with macros in the A and B headers:

```
// src/a/a.h
#ifndef SRC_A_H
#define SRC_A_H
#ifndef ALLOW_A
#error "you're not allowed to include A headers here"
#endif
//...
```

and

```
// src/b/b.h
#ifndef SRC_B_H
#define SRC_B_H
#ifdef ALLOW_A_INDIRECT
#define ALLOW_A
#endif

#include <a/a.h>
//...
#ifdef ALLOW_A_INDIRECT
#undef ALLOW_A
#endif
#endif // include guard
```

Now these make rules will allow A and B to build ok:

```
build/a/%.o: CPPFLAGS += -DALLOW_A
build/b/%.o: CPPFLAGS += -DALLOW_A
```

and this will allow C access only via B (and the macros in B's headers)

```
build/c/%.o: CPPFLAGS += -DALLOW_A_INDIRECT
```

Note this requires some discipline especially in B's headers, but I suppose if it sits alongside existing include guards, it ... ok, it's actually still pretty nasty.